# Class not serializable after methods are overridden

Tags: java, serialization, overriding

I override a `createSocket()` method in my test cases to pas in a mocked Socket.  After doing this the objects aren't serializable anymore.

Here's a example of what doesn't work.

**Foo.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3109852436898487119L;

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("Foo");
    }
}
```

**FooTest.java**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTest extends TestCase {

    // this passes
    @Test
    public void testFooIsSerializable() throws IOException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        out.writeObject(foo);
    }

    // this throws a java.io.NotSerializableException
    @Test
    public void testFooIsStillSerializableAfterBarIsOverridden()
            throws IOException {

        // Eclipse gives me the warning "The serializable class  does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long"
        // Adding it doesn't help
        Foo foo = new Foo() {
            @Override
            public void bar() {
                System.out.println("Bar");
            }
        };

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        out.writeObject(foo);
    }
}
```

**The stack trace when running FooTest with JUnit:**

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: FooTest
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at FooTest.testFooIsStillSerializableAfterBarIsOverridden(FooTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

What is the problem with this?  I have to admit, that I didn't dive too deep into Java's Serializable interface and more or less just followed Eclipse's quick fixes.

**To be more specific to my implementation:**

I have a class that should send an instance of itself via a ObjectOutputStream.

Is this a fundamentally wrong approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is you have an anonymous inner class, which by definition **contains a (compiler-generated) reference to the instance of the outer class (`FooTest`) which created it**. Since serialization by default includes all members of the object, the runtime tries to serialize the `FooTest` object too - and *that* is not serializable (as it was not meant to be). This is attested by the error message:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: FooTest
```

Thus if you turn your anonymous class into an explicit `static` inner class, the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a serialVersionUID if you want to serialize/deserialize:

```
   Foo foo = new Foo() {
     static final serialVersionUID = 348723598723589723L;
        @Override
        public void bar() {
            System.out.println("Bar");
        }
   };
```

Comment: as mentioned in a comment in my question's sourcecode this doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

> After doing this the objects aren't serializable anymore.

You don't have any evidence of that. All you have is an Eclipse *warning.* What happens when you execute?

Comment: A java.io.NotSerializableException is thrown.

Comment: @Zoran Zaric: Naming which class?

Comment: @Zoran Zaric So as it says there, what is not serializable is `FooTest`, not `Foo`. The reason for that is that constructing an anonymous inner class creates a secret reference to the containing class, in this case `FooTest`, which isn't serializable. In other words the test is invalid. To make a valid test you would have to define a *static class* that extends Foo and overrides the method.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new annyonymous inner class that extends `Foo` by overriding its `bar` method. This newly created class does not implement the `Serializable` interface, and thus cannot be serialized.

**EDIT:**
Your subclass is withing `FooTest`, so this class with its inner classes are serialized. This is why `FooTest` would have to be serializable!

Comment: I guess a anonymous inner class can't implement interfaces, so I have to create a inner class that extends my original class?

Comment: I was completely wrong, I just thought that could be a problem. But as the inner class will also "inherit" its super class's interfaces, it is of course serializable. I created an example similar to yours, and it just works as expected