# Class not serializable exception when creatin an inner class in java

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization

My code is similar to this thread.
[Class not serializable after methods are overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662529/class-not-serializable-after-methods-are-overridden?newreg=89e2c3fc5b4541b6ad23d7a76ae54b62)

But my goal is to send a method to be processed on another computer.
So, i created this class which exists on both ends. When i'm about to serialize the class, i override the method just as shown in above thread, i get the non serializable exception.
I saw in the above thread that i must create a static inner class. How can i do this?! An anonymus inner class cant be static!
And if i explicit the class name, i'll have a problem on the de-serialization end of the application.

Client Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Socket client = new Socket("192.168.25.22", 62222);
        System.out.println("Cliente conectado");
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        try { 
            Task t =(Task) input.readUnshared();
            System.out.println("Objeto recebido...");
            t.myTask();
            System.out.println("ok");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("ERRO!");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

            try {
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(62222);
                System.out.println("Listening on 62222...");

                Socket client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("New client connected with IP: " + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

                 Task t = new Task(null){@Override public void myTask(){System.out.println("Olá");}};


               //Task tz = new Tsk(null);

                ObjectOutputStream output;
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                output.writeUnshared(t);
                output.close();

                System.out.println("Task created");
                System.out.println("Objeto enviado.");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


}
```

Task Class Code:

```
 public class Task implements Serializable{
 List<Object> dataImput;
 List<Object> dataOutput;
 boolean finished;
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 595012310163575L;

 public Task(List<Object> dataImput){
     this.finished=false;
     this.dataImput= dataImput;

 }

 public void myTask(){
     System.out.println("Not Implemented.");
 }

public boolean isFinished() {
    return finished;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to send a method to be processed on another computer.

You can't. You can send an instance of an object. Not the same thing.

> I saw in the above thread that i must create a static inner class.

Static *nested* class. 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms.

> How can i do this?! An anonymus inner class cant be static!

Correct. So you can't use an anonymous inner class. Your design is wrong. Change it.

> And if i explicit the class name, i'll have a problem on the de-serialization end of the application.

I don't know what this means, or what problem you're referring to.